# Incorrect polygon for New York State in ggplot2 maps

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot data on New York state map. I am using map_data code. But If you look at polygon, It shows extra piece which is actually not part of New York state? Any ideas how can I apply filter on map data to remove that?

```
ny <- map_data("state", region="new york")
s1 <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=ny, aes(x=long, y=lat)) 
s2 <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=ny, aes(x=long, y=lat))
grid.arrange(s1, s2, ncol=2)
```

Output:
geom_point shows correct boundary, but not polygon
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state is actually composed of multiple polygons which are not connected. You just need to tell ggplot which points go with which groups. This is done by mapping your data to the `group` argument of `aes()`. See the documentation [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_group_order.html), although it would be nicer if they had a map example.

So how do you know which points go with which groups? The data frame returned by `map_data()` contains a `group` column. See:

```
head(ny)
ny$group
```

To plot the map correctly, use:

```
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = ny, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
```