# R: Overlay state map on longitude/latitude plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, zipcode

I have produced a plot of zipcodes on a grid of longitude and latitude. However, I would like to add the outline for the state of Pennsylvania to this plot. I am not sure how to go about doing this. Here is the code I have so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zipcode)
data(zipcode)


toplot <- merge(zipcode, nhmzipuse, sort = FALSE, by.x = "zip", by.y = "zip")

ggplot(toplot, aes(longitude, latitude)) + geom_point(aes(color=count))
```

Here is what my plot looks like currently:

[image: My current plot looks like:]

I know that I need to somehow get data for the border of the state of Pennsylvania and merge it with my data, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Any recommendations are much appreciated!

Comment: [Here's a new york example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41993761/903061).

Comment: Here is another good starting point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924348/how-do-i-plot-the-map-of-east-africa-kenya-uganda-and-tanzania-in-r-with-libr.  The links in the answer provide a very good starting guide